# Double tap menu on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, node.js, iphone

I created a web in wordpress with "Moco WP" template. It works ok on Windows and Android devices, but when I try to see it on iOS (iPhone) I have to click menu twice to make it work. This issue happens with Chrome and Safari. I upload a picture of the problem for you. Thanks! [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1hT8.png)

Answer (score 0):

in `/moco-wp/css/style.css` remove this part

```
header nav li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

you can move that to a media query to target only devices that can hover

```
@media (any-hover: hover) {
  header nav li a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

if you want the same functionality, you can attach to the touchstart event of the links and apply a class as soon as you touch down on them

Comment: Thanks for your answer and helping me. Do you mean about that line of code? I erase it and it doesn't work, or I think I did it wrong, idk. I upload a picture of own-menu.js file. Thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/s/cruhusk0zog9brn/asfa.png?dl=0

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/UqrgcYAm here's the file with the parts commented out. try it out and be sure to refresh a couple times to clear the cache

Comment: It doesnt work for me :( I put that file on own-menu.js and refresh and It doesnt work. Still works on Android fine but not on iOS. Its weird

Comment: @JuanBautistaDíaz sorry, i dug deeper and you can fix this by removing lines 388 to 390 in your /moco-wp/css/style.css `header nav li a:hover:after {width: 100%;}`

Comment: Absolutely grateful! It works for me. The only detail is that the menu doesnt disappear when I clic it, I don't know if it is possible to do. I put a video for example.https://www.dropbox.com/s/61rdjjtukc9dbb9/Video%208-10-18%2010%2029%2034%20p.%20m..mov?dl=0

Comment: @JuanBautistaDíaz ah, go back and uncomment out the stuff in own-menu.js. that should fix it (if it was working before). If that doesn’t work I’ll help you out